# Java script It works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The script on my site does not work correctly. It works only for the first post. Help please understand. Thank you.

[Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erRPR.jpg)

Code to get my post

```
function render($Post) {

   ob_start();
?>          
             <div class="post-1">                        
               <div <?php //post_class(); ?> id="post-<?= $Post->ID; ?>">          
                 <div class="My-title"> 
                 <h3><a href="<?= get_permalink($Post->ID); ?>"><?= $Post->post_title; ?></a> </h3>                              
                 </div>    
                 <div class="post-2">     
                   <span id="read_more">Reed more</span> 
                   <div id='read'>
                    <?= apply_filters('the_content', $Post->post_content); ?> 
                   </div> 
                   <span id='hidden'>Turn</span>   
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>  
   <?php return ob_get_clean(); 
}
```

My JavaScrip

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#read_more').click(function(){
        $('#read').slideDown(200);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#hidden').show(200);
    });
    $('#hidden').click(function(){
            $('#read').slideUp(200);
            $(this).hide();
            $('#read_more').show(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#read')` will find the *first* element with that id (and ids are supposed to be unique anyway). I recommend switching to a class name and using jQuery's `siblings()` function (e.g. `$(this).siblings('.read').slideDown(200);`)

Comment: To my regret does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `class` name instead of `id`

Please consider using the following code:

PHP:

```
function render($Post) {
   ob_start();
?>          
             <div class="post-1">                        
               <div>          
                 <div class="My-title"> 
                 <h3><a href="<?= get_permalink($Post->ID); ?>"><?= $Post->post_title; ?></a> </h3>                              
                 </div>    
                 <div class="post-2">     
                   <span class="read_more">Read more</span> 
                   <div class="read">
                    <?= apply_filters('the_content', $Post->post_content); ?> 
                   </div> 
                   <span class="hidden">Turn</span>   
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>  
   <?php return ob_get_clean(); 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.read_more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.read').slideDown(200);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.hidden').show(200);
    });
    $('.hidden').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.read').slideUp(200);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.read_more').show(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. But now after clicking read more, the turn button disappears.